# Regular expression for email

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

I tried the reg expression

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+
```

for the email validation.

Since I want the user to allow submitting even with the empty email address.
So I changed the reg ex to

```
(^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+)?
```

But this expression accepts any email address without any validation.

Comment: Your expression will accept anything because it can match the empty string (the ? meaning zero or one times) and every string "contains" the matching string. You want to compare the whole string, so put ^at the beginning and $ at the end - this way nothing BUT your regex can occur in the string. So either it is empty OR the complete pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Konerak!!!!
I changed the expression to

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+)?$
```

and this is working for me.

Comment: And what about the + character?

Comment: isn't underscore forbidden in host names?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome. http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: I think this is unrealistic because RFC822 includes a lot of legacy address types that are rarely needed or supported by current software.

Comment: yeah, this is not practical. far better is this, and the discussion around it: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Answer (score 1):

A good bit of info on doing this is available at [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

As that page will tell you, it's extremely difficult to pass any and all RFC822-compliant addresses with a regex.  You need to ask yourself just how important this is to your application.

Personally I would recommend, if applicable, simply asking users to enter the email address twice and then confirm with a confirmation email.  That way you don't run the risk of erroneously rejecting a valid email address (an extremely annoying situation for users which will likely lose your site some customers).

Answer (score 1):

[How to: Verify That Strings Are in Valid E-Mail Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)